# How to project onto a nonlinear subspace?

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics, normal-distribution, nonlinear-optimization

If i have a function $f : \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which i want to approximate by a function of the form $F_k(x) = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i N(\mu_i,\sigma_i)(x)$, for some constants $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$, and where $N(\mu, \sigma)$ is the $d$-dimensional normal distribution with mean $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and variance $\sigma^2 \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$, how would i go about doing this?

Or in other words, how to find $(a_1,...,a_k,\mu_1,...,\mu_k,\sigma_1,...,\sigma_k)$ which minimizes $||f - F_k||$ in some appropriate norm?
I guess the general question would be how to project a function onto a nonlinear subspace?

Comment: Do you denote by $N(\mu,\sigma)$ the pdf or cdf?

Comment: The pdf, i.e., $N(\mu,\sigma)(x) = (2\pi)^{\frac{d}{2}}\det(\sigma)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^\top\sigma^{-1}(x-\mu))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example [K-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) or maybe if you want something more powerful you can use [Expectation Maximization (EM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm).

You can also homebrew your own [iterated reweighted linear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares) solution which mimics any of these two depending on choice of reweighting functions.

Comment: IRLLS seems to be what I'm looking for, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mattkb Yes it is very nice and powerful. I have done a couple of my own estimators using it.